# Equilibrium saturation/depostion rate calculation

Tags: equilibrium, phase, sublimation

I found the [Knudsen/Langmuir equation](http://thermopedia.com/content/1163/) for calculating the sublimation rate of a solid. If I have a closed system, once the vapor reaches the saturation pressure, the solid will continue sublimating but will deposit at the same rate in a dynamic equilibrium.

Is there a relatively simply (ie, not-statistical mechanics modeling) way to calculate the dynamic rate of sublimation/deposition?